# adding dynamic arrays and removing trailing 0's

Tags: c++, pointers

I am trying to implement this function to add two dynamic a
rrays, however when I implement this into my main it completely crashes, I have no idea why...

I cannot understand why the program shuts down except the exit code on scite says exit code 255. But that is not helpful. Any idea what the problem may be?

Comment: You have an off-by-one error, in the loop initializing `sum`. Its loop condition should be `k < max`. It's possible you have other similar errors.

Comment: Un-solicited side note: For what it's worth, using a size-constructed `std::vector` is almost (negligible, if any, difference) exactly the same a using a bare array, yet it offers much cleaner looking code, offers exception safety, and protects against memory leaks.

Comment: As for the crashes, please build with debug information ("Debug" variant if using e.g. Visual Studio, or adding the `-g` flag if using GCC/clang) and run your program in a debugger. The debugger will stop at the crash, and you will be able to see both the call-stack, and examine values of variables.

Comment: That indentation "style" is weird.

Comment: There are a lot of pointers in that code that don't need to be pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one:

```
for (int k=0; k<=max; k++)
```

This goes out of range. Instead allocate memory for `[max+1]` elements, **since there shall be `max+1` terms in the polynomial**.

```
sum = new int[ max + 1 ];
```

Also, the `j` loop should start from `max`.

```
for (j=max; j>0 && sum[j]==0; --j);
```

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I've advised to allocate memory for max+1 elements since the polynomial shall most probably have max+1 terms where max is the degree of the polynomial.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo on this line:

```
for (j=max-1; j>0 && sum[j]==0; --j); 
                                    ^here
```

The next statement `int *tmp=sum;` does not get executed.

Also the for loop should probably be

```
for (j=max-1; j>=0 && sum[j]==0; --j)
                ^ //don't forget the last member
```

Comment: It sure gets executed, just after the loop have ended. It's also probable that it's the purpose of the loop, to find the `j` where the `sum[j]` is zero in which case the loop is fine as it is.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Yes your are probably right. Indentation is just weird.

Comment: @John the j>0 seems to be on purpose to leave atleast one element in the resulting polynomial.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of nice things about C++ is all the [standard containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) (like [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)) and [standard algorithms available](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm). For example you could use vectors and backwards iterators and [`std::find_if_not`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) to find the last non-zero value.

Like

```
// Create a vector of a specific size, and initialize it
std::vector<int> sum(std::max(a->degree, b->degree), 0);

// Fill it up...

// Find the last non-zero value
auto last_non_zero = std::find_if_not(sum.rbegin(), sum.rend(),
    [](const int& value){ return value == 0; });

if (last_non_zero == sum.rbegin())
{
    // No zeroes found
}
else if (last_non_zero == sum.rend())
{
    // All of it was zero
    sum.clear();
}
else
{
    std::vector<int> temp(last_non_zero, sum.rend())
    std::reverse(temp);  // Because the `temp` vector is reversed
    sum = temp;
}
```

After this the vector `sum` should have been stripped of trailing zeroes.

Comment: AFAIK a polynomial generally has (p->degree+1) terms. Hence size of sum should be one more than max(a->degree,b->degree)